# How to calculate duration between datatimes across rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
+---------+---------------------+--------+
|    name |            datetime | status |
+---------+---------------------+--------+
| object1 | 2016-05-21T05:20:56 |     OK |
| object1 | 2016-05-21T05:21:00 |     OK |
+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

I have sample above `DataSet` in Spark, how can I calculate the time difference for same object where status is `OK`?

I would like to return as below after calculating time:

```
+---------+----------+
|    name | duration | 
+---------+----------+
| object1 |        4 |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: you should go with udaf functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with built-in Spark functions and window aggregate function.

```
val names = Window.partitionBy('name).orderBy('datetime)
val withPreviousDateTime = df
  .withColumn("previousTime", lag('datetime, 1) over names)
  .withColumn(unix_timestamp('datetime) - unix_timestamp('previousTime))
```

Of course you should add at the start:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
```

So implicits, Windows and function will be visible

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to stick to `java.sql.Timestamp` for times, as they are natively supported by Spark SQL, making it easier to work with them.

Let's start with some setup:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window._

final case class Data(name: String, datetime: Timestamp, status: String)

spark.createDataset(
  sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Data("object1", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:20:56"), "OK"),
    Data("object2", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:20:57"), "OK"),
    Data("object3", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:20:58"), "OK"),
    Data("object2", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:20:58"), "KO"),
    Data("object3", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:20:59"), "OK"),
    Data("object1", Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-21 05:21:00"), "OK")
  )
)
```

Now that we have the `Dataset` ready, let's work on it:

```
val result =
  ds.
    where($"status" === "OK").
    withColumn("t", lag('datetime, 1).over(partitionBy($"name").orderBy('datetime))).
    withColumn("duration", unix_timestamp($"datetime") - unix_timestamp($"t")).
    select($"name", $"duration").where(not($"duration".isNull))
```

If you now do `result.show()` you should see the following:

```
+-------+--------+
|   name|duration|
+-------+--------+
|object1|       4|
|object3|       1|
+-------+--------+
```

In the query you:

1. filter out non-`OK` rows
2. append to each row the `lag` to the previous one
3. compute a new column that contains the difference between those two
4. project only the columns you want and filter out unwanted rows

Comment: Ok how it differs from my answer? :) The query is almost the same, only with additional status and non null filter

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it while you were writing yours, feel free to integrate my addition to yours.

Comment: thanks much this really helps , one more question though I am actually reading data from Json file val oname = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  `objectname`, `event_status`, `@timestamp` FROM actual_data  ORDER BY `@timestamp`")

Comment: thanks much this really helps , one more question though I am actually reading data from Json file  and then using sqlcontext val oname = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  `objectname`, `event_status`, `@timestamp` FROM actual_data  ORDER BY `@timestamp`") how I can create dataset from oname that I have used

Comment: I am using zepplin notebook Timestamp is not available when I try using suggested solutions , any idea ?

Comment: sorry asking so much I need to convert this datetime format as well 2016-05-21T05:20:56 so I can calculate time is there any function available so I can extract time

Answer (score 0):

Select name,lead(dt) over(partition by name order by dt) -dt duration from t where status=OK

Its called wlndow function or analytical function